# Surface resistance calculation for non-rectangle surface

Tags: electricity

[image]

I have thin film on dielectric with equal surface resistance trapeze and when applying voltage (at grey area) hot area appears. How to calculate resistance field for trapeze to eliminate hot spots and create equal thermal map?

Comment: The best way is to use finite element analysis.

Comment: There are methods one can use to calculate the current density in your case, but what would be the point? You did not tell us which parameters you can change to avoid hot spots, so you would be stuck with the calculated results.

Comment: I can change resistance gradually across surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mentioned in the comment that you can change the conductivity $\sigma(\vec{r})$ of the film . Then you have the following for the potential $\phi(\vec{r})$ and electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$:
$$\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{r})=-\vec{E}(\vec{r}).$$
You also have
$$\vec{j}(\vec{r})=\sigma(\vec{r})\vec{E}(\vec{r}),$$
where $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$ is the current density, and
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j}(\vec{r})=0,$$
thus
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\sigma(\vec{r})\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{r})\right)=0.$$
So you have a linear scalar elliptic partial differential equation in two dimensions for $\phi(\vec{r})$. You can also get the boundary conditions at the top and at the bottom (where the potential is constant, so you have Dirichlet conditions) and on the left and on the right (where the normal component of the current density vanishes, so you have the Neumann conditions). Thus, you can pose an [elliptic boundary value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_boundary_value_problem) and solve it numerically. Then you can calculate the current density using the above formulas.

Comment: if i set conductivity map for these trapeze ( ex. 5 Ohm at the top right 30 Ohm to botom left etc.) will it simplify calculation and how can i add this to equations ?

Comment: @user247471 : I am not quite sure what  you have in mind. If you mean you provide different but constant conductivity in different squares of an imaginary grid covering the film, then no, I don't think it will not simplify calculation. And I don't like the units you use for conductivity.

Comment: I can raise thickness of film at certain area and by that lower surface resistance at that area (measuring by four probe method), that is how i can change conductivity. The problem i need to solve is which resistance i need to get at trapeze grid to have equal heat dissipation. And if manually set resistance at grid how can i calculate heat dissipation across trapeze area or any other 2d surface?

Comment: @user247471 : I described how one can solve the direct problem: given the conductivity, calculate the potential and the current density. If one knows the current density and the conductivity, it is easy to calculate heat dissipation as resistive heating. I don't know how to solve the inverse problem: find the conductivity providing uniform heat dissipation, but you can try initial conductivity function, solve the direct problem, and gradually improve the conductivity function and heating uniformity. However, I recommend smooth conductivity functions to avoid serious problems.

Comment: Thank you for clarification